# Why are my NAS drive transfers so slow?

Tags: networking, macos, router, nas

I've a rMBP with 802.11ac, connected to an Asus RT-AC66U on 5GHz and a WD My Cloud EX2.

If I transfer large files via the router from the Macbook to the NAS drive I see a mere ~10MB/s (80Mbps say).

I believe the WD is on a 1Gbps connection to the router as the link light is green, I've tried various cat5e cables without any difference.

The OSX wireless diagnostics info suggests I'm connected at 434Mbps to the router - I'd have thought this should be the limiting factor, but I'm not getting anywhere near it.

ETA: The transfer speed also seems to be slightly (~1MBps) slower than internet downloads.

ETA: If I sit two feet from the router the Macbook reports sync'ing at 1300Mbps. I *still* don't get more than about ~10MB/s transferring to the NAS. Similarly, iperf to another device records an absolute maximum of 118Mbps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Troubleshooting slow Wi-Fi performance writing to NAS](http://superuser.com/questions/729358/troubleshooting-slow-wi-fi-performance-writing-to-nas)

Comment: To test your wireless link, you need another PC and `iperf`. To test your NAS, you need a wired connection and FTP.

Comment: That 434 Mbps is the speed of the link itself including all in-air headers and so. Achievable real speed would be maybe about 100-120 Mbps in this case. And this with nobody else in the range of your wifi, else interference would lower the speed even more.

Comment: @Marki555: That’s simply not true. I have the same WiFi setup and get 208 Mbit/s TX out of 264 Mbit/s indicated TX speed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. No luck so far, original post updated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this recently after giving up and getting another device. The WD My Cloud EX2 has a few "RAID Modes".

I was in JBOD, switching to RAID 0 I can reach speeds that max out the 1Gbps connection - I assume there must be a bug with the JBOD implementation.

[image]